# ¿Cómo generar valores aleatorios sin que se repitan en Android Studio?

Tags: java, array, random

Quiero generar elementos aleatorios de un array pero que no se repitan.

```
    Integer [] sonidos_numbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5};


                int valorRandom = getRandom();

                if (valorRandom == 0 )
                {
                    soundPool.play(cabeza,1,1,0,0,1);
                    imagen_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            imagen_principal_1.setImageResource(images[images_numbers[0]]);
                            imagen_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            soundPool.play(correcto,1,1,0,0,1);
                            turns++;

                            checkEnd();
                        }
                    });

    private static int getRandom(Integer[] array)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int start = 0;
        int end = 6;
        int playRandom = r.nextInt(end-start) + start;
        return array[playRandom];
    }
```

En mi código los elementos se generan aleatoriamente pero muchas de las veces se repite, me gustaría que una vez que un elemento ha sido generado no se vuelva a generar.

Answer (score 1):

la solucion es sencilla.... create otro array identico ,donde iras guardando cada nuevo (no repetido)  numero aleatorio que se genere, y cada vez que se genere un numero aleatorio con un metodo contains aplicado sobre este nuevo array

por ejemplo asi

```
 int [] sonidos_numbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        Random r = new Random();

        int start = 0;
        int end = sonidos_numbers.length-1;

      int[] miarrayrepetido = new int[sonidos_numbers.length];

        int nuevonumero=0;

        while(true){

            int playRandom = r.nextInt(end-start) + start;

            if( Arrays.asList(miarrayrepetido).contains(playRandom)==false){//el numeroaleatorio no existe en el array por lo tanto no se ha generado ,no  es repetido
                miarrayrepetido[nuevonumero]=playRandom;
                nuevonumero++;
                break;


            }
        }
    }
```

con esto se ira generando numeros aleatorios , hasta que se genere un numero aleatorio que no este guardado en miarray, y por lo tanto que no se haya generado

Comment: Buenos dias como estas, tengo dos preguntas estoy trabajando con sonidos y no se si por esa razon la condición del if me genera un error en el .contains, y la otra es que retornaria del private static get Random, muchas gracias

Comment: Actualizado el codigo de mi solucion con tu nuevo codigo, mira como funciona ahora, lo unico que deberas hacer , es agrupar o retocar este codigo para que funcione  a tu gusto , según como lo tengas en la aplicación, por ejemplo, si quieres que se genere un nuevo numero aleatorio cada vez que se presiona un button

Answer (score 1):

Para estos casos, yo suelo utilizar un método que consiste en:

1. Iniciar la lista de valores a generar.
2. Generar un número aleatorio entre 1 y la longitud de la lista.
3. Seleccionar el elemento de la lista correspondiente a ese número
4. Eliminar de la lista el elemento seleccionado
5. Volver al punto 2.

Esto garantiza que no se repiten elementos de forma sencilla y a partir de cualquier tipo de lista de valores a generar, pudiendo ser enteros, caracteres, frases, imágenes, etc...

Te pongo un ejemplo para tu caso concreto en Java/Android, a partir de tu propio ejemplo:

```
/* debes cambiar la declaración de tu tipo de datos por ArrayList */
/* Integer [] sonidos_numbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5}; */

private static ArrayList<Integer> sonidos_numbers = new ArrayList<>(); 


/* debes iniciar ArrayList con datos para la generación aleatoria */
/* En el constructor de tu clase es un lugar apropiado */
initLista();



/*   .... EL RESTO DE TU CÓDIGO   */
int valorRandom = getRandom();
...

/* declaración nueva para el generador de aleatorios sin repetidos constenidos en el ArrayList declarado inicialmente */
private static int getRandom()
{
    int valorSeleccionado = -1;

    if (sonidos_numbers.size() > 0){
        Random r = new Random();

        /* generar el indice aleatorio a usar */
        int playRandom = r.nextInt(sonidos_numbers.size());

        /* capturar valor a devolver */
        valorSeleccionado = sonidos_numbers.get(playRandom);

        /* reducir LISTA de valores para la próxima generación */
        sonidos_numbers.remove(playRandom);
    }

    return valorSeleccionado;
}


/* Función para inicializar el vector con los datos a generar, en tu caso valores del 0 al 5 */    
private static void initLista()
{
    for (Integer i=0;i<=5;i++){
        sonidos_numbers.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola que tal muchas gracias por la ayuda, al ejecutar el codigo que adjuntaste el valor de valorSeleccionado no es generado

Comment: @cristianrodriguezbarba, Debes usar la función de iniciar la lista InitList antes de llamar la primera vez al getRandom.  (es decir, el paso 1 de mi descripción inical)

Comment: he editado el codigo de la pregunta para que puedas ver como me gustaria usar el numero aleatorio de la función getRandom,

Comment: @cristianrodriguezbarba, reeditada mi respuesta para "ofrecerte" una solución a partir de tu código actual...

Comment: he editado tu codigo por mi codigo actual para que tengas una mejor idea de lo que quiero obtener, me gustaria obtener como lo mencione en la pregunta que el valor randomico se genere pero sin repetir, una sola vuelta, espero me hayas entendido

Comment: lo que pides es lo que hace el código publicado.

Comment: ¿Puede que estés pidiendo obtener una secuencia de 6 valores aleatorios sin repetidos?... entonces llama 6 veces la función getRandom...

Comment: Si exactamente es lo que deseo hacer, obtener seis valores numéricos sin que estos sean repetidos, pero con el codigo que genero estos se repiten idefinidamente

Comment: Los valores no se pueden repetir. Es imposible, porque el algoritmo elimina los números ya utilizados. (excepto si vuelves a inicializar la lista actual otra vez)

Comment: Con el codigo que generaste inicialmente verdad,

Comment: Tu modificación no ha sido ni validada ni realizada. (lo la ves tu). Yo puedo consultarla y no tiene nada que ver con mi código, pero absolutamente nada. Por eso tu modificación es simplemente repetir tu código y por eso no funciona. Y como bien dices, el mio antes de tu modificación si funciona.

Comment: Puedes publicar tu codigo nuevamente, muchas gracias y disculpas por todas las molestias :(

Comment: No es ninguna molestia. Si te sirve mi código, adaptalo a tus necesidaes, por ejemplo, llena tu array, haciendo `sonido[0]=getRandom(); sonido[1]=getRandom(); ....`.  Nota: Anularé tu edición para que puedas ver el código anterior...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, realmente fue muy útil, acabo de obtener el resultado esperado, gracias a personas como tu mi sueño de convertirme en un programador se va haciendo realidad día a día